# CSS error, "Invalid Property Value"

Tags: css, transform

in CSS, I get a error, "Invalid Property Value" when I inspect the transform element of Service section of  Wall street theme. Can anyone please help me with the steps to correct it?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps is not a error but may indicate that there are other CSS rules that override these one.

Comment: Your css is correct (fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/wxo8rd0p/2/ ) , check if it's not overwritten by an other selector ;)

Comment: Can you please let me know where or how I can check if it's being overwritten?

Comment: Two ways: Check your css file, or put `!important` on your transform rule to see if it forces it to work (but don't use it in production - !important is evil).

Comment: You can also check the right panel on your firebug and go down the selector to see where is defined other -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) property :)

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your help... there was a issue in my browser, I guess as it worked well in firefox

Comment: If the CSS is correct, then `invalid property value` is an invalid description.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally safely ignore "invalid property value" errors in CSS when you're using vendor specific prefixes since the validation of these values is not always accurate.

Note however that you're currently rotating by 360deg, which obviously doesn't do much :)